# Gl_UseProgram doesn't affect shaders

Tags: c++, opengl

It seems like my useProgram doesn't bind the shader so I cant set uniforms to it. But when I use GlUseProgram in the compile code for the shader I can set uniforms. I am using a resourcemanager to handle the shaders and textures and a Game file to handle the shader/texter/game setup.

Shader.h:

```
class Shader
{
    Shader() {};
    void Compile(const std::string& vertexSource, const std::string& fragmentSource, const char* geometrySource = nullptr);
    Shader  &Use();
}
```

Shader.cpp

```
Shader & Shader::Use()
}
    glUseProgram(this->ID);
    return *this;
{

void Shader::Compile(const std::string& vertexSource, const std::string& 
    fragmentSource, const char* geometrySource)
{
    unsigned int vShader, fShader, gShader;

    const char* src1 = vertexSource.c_str();
    const char* src2 = fragmentSource.c_str();

    vShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vShader, 1, &src1, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vShader);
    checkCompileErrors(vShader, "VERTEX");

    fShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fShader, 1, &src2, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fShader);
    checkCompileErrors(fShader, "FRAGMENT");

    if (geometrySource != nullptr)
    {
        gShader = glCreateShader(GL_GEOMETRY_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(gShader, 1, &geometrySource, NULL);
        glCompileShader(gShader);
        checkCompileErrors(gShader, "error");
    }

    this->ID = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(this->ID, vShader);
    glAttachShader(this->ID, fShader);

    if (geometrySource != nullptr)
    {
        glAttachShader(this->ID, gShader);
    }
    glLinkProgram(this->ID);
    checkCompileErrors(this->ID, "PROGRAM");

    //glUseProgram(this->ID);

    glDeleteShader(vShader);
    glDeleteShader(fShader);
    if (geometrySource != nullptr)
    {
        glDeleteShader(gShader);
    }
}
```

You can see where I have comment out GlUseProgram. If I dont comment it out the shader will work properly but if I do comment It out it will not work.

ResourceManager.h:

```
class ResourceManager
{
public:
    // Resource storage
    static std::unordered_map<std::string, Shader>    shader;
    static Shader loadShader(const std::string& vShaderSource, std::string filename);
    static Shader getShader(std::string name);
    static Shader loadShaderFromFile(const std::string& vShaderFile);
```

ResourceManager.cpp

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, Shader> ResourceManager::shader;
Shader ResourceManager::loadShader(const std::string& vShaderSource, std::string filename)
{
    shader[filename] = loadShaderFromFile(vShaderSource);
    return shader[filename];
}

Shader ResourceManager::getShader(std::string filename)
{
    return shader[filename];
}

Shader ResourceManager::loadShaderFromFile(const std::string& vShaderFile)
{
    enum class ShaderType
    {
        none = -1, vertex = 0, fragment = 1
    };

    std::fstream path(vShaderFile);
    std::stringstream ss[2];
    std::string string;
    ShaderType type = ShaderType::none;

    while (std::getline(path, string))
    {
        if (string.find("shader") != std::string::npos) 
        {
            if (string.find("vertex") != std::string::npos)
            {
                type = ShaderType::vertex;
            }
            if (string.find("fragment") != std::string::npos)
            {
                type = ShaderType::fragment;
            }
        }
        else
            ss[(int)type] << string << "\n";
    }

    std::string vertexCode = ss[0].str();
    std::string fragmentCode = ss[1].str();
    const char* geomtryCode = nullptr;

    Shader shader;
    shader.Compile(vertexCode, fragmentCode);

    return shader;
}
```

And finally.
Game.cpp:

```
void Game::Init()
{
    ResourceManager::loadShader("res/Shader/shader.shader", "sprite");
    ResourceManager::getShader("sprite").Use().setUniform1i("image", 0);
    ResourceManager::getShader("sprite").setUniformMatrix4fv("projection", projection);
}
```

Would someone explain why it doesn't seems to work?

Comment: 1) Welcome to SO!  **2)** Please add indentation to your code. **3)** `glCreateShader`, `glCreateProgram`, `glShaderSource`, `glCompileShader`, `glAttachShader`, `glLinkProgram`, all of them are required. After linkage is right, then you can call `glUseProgram`. Compare with your code.

Comment: Hello!, Yes I have added all these features but I felt it wasnt necessary to bring it to the code file. Because I know my shaders work if I use GlUseProgram in the compile state of the shader, and what I want to achive is that you most use the Use function the enable the program ;)

Comment: The missing `{}` for `Shader::Use()` is a typo in your code or you did an incomplete copy & paste?

Comment: Yes im sorry for that, I fixed it now!

Comment: Do you have a destructor for Shader? It seems you are returning Shader objects by value from getShader etc. If you are doing shallow copies of them, and the destructor destroys their GL object, you'll end up with dangling resources.

Comment: Hello!, I have trying to fix this for a while now and I think i fixed it. I hade a destructor for the shader but I didnt include it in the codefile :P. But i just deleted the destructor from the h and cpp file and my shader started to work. I have no clue why it is working now but.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into the [4.6 specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf), section 7.1, about `DeleteShader()` it only says:

> If shader is not attached to any program object, it is deleted
>   immediately. Otherwise, shader is flagged for deletion and will be
>   deleted when it is no longer attached to any program object.

At section 7.3, about `UseProgram()`

> An INVALID_OPERATION error is generated if program has not been linked
>   successfully. The current rendering state is not modified.

and

> While a program object is in use, applications are free to modify
>   attached shader objects, compile attached shader objects, attach
>   additional shader objects, and detach shader objects. These operations
>   do not affect the link status or executable code of the program
>   object.

You see, apparently you could call `glUseProgram()` anywhere after  successfully linking.

If it doesn't work for you it could be a bug in the driver of your gfx card.

**But** read it again and pay attention to it tells about **detach** shaders, not **delete** shaders.

In short, detach a shader (`glDetachShader`) before deleting it (`glDeleteShader`).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think I solved the problem through delete the destructor for the Shader class. Dont know why it works but apperently